# possible to add crossorigin attribute to script tags generated by angular cli?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Is it possible to add crossorigin attribute to script tags generated by angular cli?

when running my angular app, script tags are added to the end of my index.html:

`<script src="runtime-es2015.3d05cbd29d24231258bf.js" type="module"></script>`
`<script src="polyfills-es2015.28da6787754ec8436843.js" type="module"></script>`
`<script src="main-es2015.4106b7f4d43a05cb792d.js" type="module"></script>`

Is it possible to configure angular-cli so that when those tags are included in the build index.html, that the crossorigin attribute be added to the script declaration:

`<script src="runtime-es2015.3d05cbd29d24231258bf.js" type="module" crossorigin="use-credentials"></script>`

**Why am I asking this?**  My application is deployed to an apache server that uses basic authentication.  When using Firefox or Edge (chrome is fine) the requests for the javascript modules receive a 401 error because the Authorization header is not set.  If the crossorigin tag is added, the Authorization header is set.  Therefore, I need to be able to add that crossorigin attribute if I want my users to be able to use FF or Edge.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: would `crossorigin="use-credentials"` use credentials if the request is *same origin*? Perhaps you should read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) carefully

Comment: (not related to the crossorigin attribute, but attributes in general) Take a look at this GitHub issue. Seems to be some discussion going on around how to do this. There's a couple of options in the thread it looks like: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3323

Answer (score 6):

As of angular/cli 8.1 ([PR](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/14844)) there is a flag that can be set to alter the script tags (and link tags for that matter) in the index.html

> --crossOrigin=none|anonymous|use-credentials
>   Define the crossorigin attribute setting of elements that provide CORS support.
>   Default: none
>   https://angular.io/cli/build

another alternative would have been to use a post build npm step that unwraps the index.html and alters it based on various needs

[cheeriojs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) comes in mind for these kind of manipulations on the server side (check this [example](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7824#issuecomment-332498000) for some more details)